# Pure geometry - Textbook(s) or course(s)

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question

I've recently discovered the beauty of pure mathematics and I played around with various geometry problems I could find here and there (past papers in IMO or STEP exams and stuff I could find right here on MSE).

Having no training in said area, I found myself looking around for a lot of clues, hints and theorems that were needed to solve the problems I encountered.

That said, rather than sporadically searching for problems and results, I was wondering if anyone here may point me in the right direction, regarding courses or textbooks.

What I'm looking for is basically encapsulated by the following:

---

$\bullet$ Manner of thinking and problems in the spirit of the IMO, or any such approach that concentrates on creativity rather than algorithmic procedures like the ones used in engineering or calculus

$\bullet$ There should be no obvious connection to calculus (i.e. differential geometry)

$\bullet$ Detailed proofs of the results presented

$\bullet$ Sets of problems, or questions meant for the reader to answer

---

Comment: What do you mean with "pure geometry"? You mention some problems on IMO but you didn't provide examples of such problems.

Comment: How are problems involving calculus not creative?

Comment: You could do much worse than Coxeter's texts. [Introduction to Geometry](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Geometry-H-S-Coxeter/dp/0471504580) and [Geometry Revisited](https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0883856190/ref=pd_aw_fbt_14_img_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=06N7G23ZYXPKYZYQ3Q8D) should be the most appropriate.

Comment: @Voyska, this is basically what I'm talking about (https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Category:Olympiad_Geometry_Problems).

Comment: @EuYu, thank you for your response, both textbooks look really interesting.

Comment: My preference goes to [Geometry I](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540116585) and [Geometry II](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540170150) by M. Berger. They are real masterpieces! They give a large overview of geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently found this blog look at  [here](http://eisatopon.blogspot.gr/2016/07/blog-post_84.html)